# How to insert a <br> in a dynamically created button value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating buttons dynamicaly, for that I'm using the following code :

```
jQuery('<input/>', {
    id: id,
    type: 'button',
    value: var1 + " " +  var2 + "<br>" + var3,
}).appendTo('.div1');
```

What I want is to insert a carriage return inside the text between 2 variables, but it just prints whatever I put there as a text.

Is there any way to escape that ?

Comment: You have to escape line break sign with `\n` or use `<button>` instead of an `input`

Comment: that worked i feel stupid i simply replaced

        "<br>" with  "\n"

thanx  :D

Comment: Consider picking the right answer then ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't display HTML inside an input.  You can use a regular linebreak in this case:

```
jQuery('<input/>', {
    id: id,
    type: 'button',
    value: var1 + " " +  var2 + "\n" + var3,
}).appendTo('.div1');
```

Answer (score 1):

Just as a side note, if you need a button which can hold something other than text, like HTML markup, you can use the `<button>` tag.

```
jQuery('<button/>', {
    id: id,
    html: var1 + " " +  var2 + "<br />" + var3,
}).appendTo('.div1');
```